# internet explorer vlc layering

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, vlc

I have been working on a webpage for a little while and came across an issue where this time around googling will not suffice:

I have a VLC embedded player within a page (this works fine) but after a little while the page is supposed to time out with a warning appearing in the center of the page. In internet explorer only, this appears below the VLC player which prevents the user from selecting any options. I have tried using windowless =true and using z-index to adjust the pages however this still occurs.

I have updated all VLC content. Any ideas on what more can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you recreate your issue in jsfiddle, codepen or something similar, so people get a better idea about what you're trying to achieve but can't?

Comment: The code is really dispersed while all being knit together. It'll take a little while to recreate all the conditions so I can work on that tonight. If anything comes to mind in the meantime let me know :)